NER with custom tags and no training data, zero shot approach help
I am building a "field tagger" for documents. Basically, a document, in my case something like a proposal or sales quote, would have a bunch of entities scattered throughout it, and we want to match each one to the field/tag that best describes it. The issue is that, though descriptive, the list of fields/tags doesnt exactly align with the existing NER entity and category types.
For example, some of the fields/tags (labels) in my case are things like: 'Ownership', 'Account Type', 'Main Competitor(s)', 'Account Name', 'Account Source', 'Industry', 'Account Number', 'Amount', 'Compare Name', 'Primary Partner Account ID', 'Active', 'Name', 'Has Open Activity', 'Probability (%)', 'Owner Alias', 'Owner ID', 'Has Line Item', 'Description', 'Account Site', 'Expected Amount', 'Account Description', 'Account Rating', 'Employees'. Things of that nature, which carry some amount of semantic meaning but perhaps not a lot.
So for instance, if the document is the text:
"The opportunity for <<ABC Company>> in the amount of <<$500,000>> is scheduled to close on <<July 30, 2024>>."

Where, at this stage, we can assume the entities have been marked so we don't have to handle recognizing what exactly is an entity in the raw document, I would want the tool to systematically go through each of the marked entities and match them to the most appropriate field/tag.
My initial approach, due to the lack of training data, has been to use a zero shot text classification approach, using facebook/bart-large-mnli, systematically iterating through the entities, passing the list of fields/tags as the labels, and a prompt asking to classify. The issue is I'm not sure that the model is semantically understanding the meaning of the labels themselves. What's worse is I'm unsure of how to pass context to the model, as simply adding it to the prompt, across the board, made predictions worse (things like company names, which were somewhat correctly identified beforehand, started to be treated as dates, etc).
Having no training data is a limit here, so my goal for this tools reflect that. It's only to build a tool that at least performs somewhat well. Frr instance, if the best label is in the top 5 most likely labels according to the model's probability distribution, I'd consider that a successful classification.
Wuld anyone be able to suggest an approach, or provide advice on how to adjust my existing one, to achieve some better results? How might I go about providing context in a way that enhances predictions? Any help would be appreciated
